# Extract URL from a web page result and display the URL in a Iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, text-extraction, twitch-api

My last clip result is located [here](https://warp.world/scripts/latest-clip?access_token=05b7nxihtqyzhwjzamlrqz9ekpkliv) which gives me something like

```
Last clip created by HeyitsLonestar while playing Deadlight - https://clips.twitch.tv/SarcasticRacySrirachaTBCheesePull
```

I would like to be able to extract just the URL and put it in an iframe like below but have no clue how:

```
<iframe
src="https://clips.twitch.tv/embed?clip=SarcasticRacySrirachaTBCheesePull"
height="360"
width="640"
frameborder="0"
scrolling="no"
allowfullscreen="true">
</iframe>
```

It seems I would need the last part of the URL to make this automated anytime a new clip is created:

```
 SarcasticRacySrirachaTBCheesePull
```

Answer (score 1):

assuming your structure always starts with **clips.twitch.tv/** you can use this regular expression to extract only the final content:

```
/^(.+\/(\w+))?/gm
```

If you want to check a example of this, you could look at this [Codepen](https://codepen.io/joaoskr/pen/bmyOrG)

Comment: The `g` (global) flag is redundant when you're just extracting one bit out of one string. The `m` (multi-line) flag doesn't apply to this problem because the OP's actual HTTP response seems to be all in one line even though the original question made it seems like multiple lines.

Answer (score 1):

If the format of the result is guaranteed to always end with the URL, you can split the string by `/` and grab the last token with:

```
result.split('/').pop()
```

While regular expressions are *regularly* used for string parsing, sometimes basic splitting just works and it's easier to follow.

Demo:

```js
var result = 'Last clip created by HeyitsLonestar while playing Deadlight - https://clips.twitch.tv/SarcasticRacySrirachaTBCheesePull';

console.log(result.split('/').pop())
```

Comment: What would the code be to check this page https://warp.world/scripts/latest-clip?access_token=05b7nxihtqyzhwjzamlrqz9ekpkliv and get that result of what you have above? The way you have it set up is just the result. Thank you this is helping.